How to catch keyboard-language-changed event for GNOME Extensions?
There is empty GHOME Extension.
It's default extension.js file:
*
* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later
*/

/* exported init */

class Extension {
    constructor() {
    }

    enable() {

      some.event(“lang-switch-event”, () => {
        log(‘Language was changed and now = ’);
      });

    }

    disable() {
    }
}

function init() {
  return new Extension();
}

How to catch keyboard-language changed event for GNOME Extensions?

please read [sask] then [edit] your question accordingly. As it stands, there is no clarity of your problem.

I would expect a DBus message to be fired when the keyboard language chances. You can set up a DBus listener. Is that what you are looking for?
